# why firebase firestore crash at [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.grpcpp"]?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

this is the crash log from test flight.
it only happens in test flight, I can not reproduce it locally, I have no idea what happed here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the library can not find ssl cert for grpc
**solution:** 
Under `FirebaseFirestore.framework`, there is a file called `gRPCCertificates-Firestore.bundle`, drag it into Xcode project. Hit Run and check.